# How does flutter recieve, the back navigation broadcast(?) from android, and iOS, Web(only mobile)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a custom, `Navigator`(and `NavigatorState`) equivalent, in-dependent of the former.

---

Equivalents which are already mimicked, using my custom stack data-struct; supporting pages, bottom sheets, alerts, bottom toasts:

- `push`
- `push_replace`

Not completed, yet:

- `pop`
- `pop_until`

---

We know, that Android, and Iphones support the following options for back navigation (pop):

```
           Android   Iphone
Top bar       Y        Y
Gesture       Y        Y
Button        Y        -
```

Among these, tab-bar is in-app, so I can directly listen to its press, but:

#### How to listen for back gesture (swipe from screen's left/right edge), and back button press actions.

Also, are these sensed directly by flutter, or the OS sends some event to the framework?

---

I checked out [`Future<bool> WidgetsBindingObserver.didPopRoute`](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didPopRoute.html): "Called when the system tells the app to pop the current route. For example, on Android, this is called when the user presses the back button."; but I

#### Need something **like** `Stream system_back_navigation_events_broadcast()`

thanks